# router.use TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router

I'm new to node.js, experts, please help.
I'm preparing a code to do user sync based on node.js + AWS Cognito + Facebook Login.  I tried an example from this [link](http://blog.backspace.academy/2015/03/using-cognito-with-node.html).

Every step runs smooth until "facebook sing in with passport" section

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
...
router.use(passport.initialize());
...
```

After adding this part in the example, I run "npm start", the following error appeared:

```
C:\workspace\nodejs\CognitoExample\routes\index.js:35
router.use(passport.initialize());
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
```

What's the meaning of "Cannot read property"?  How to fix the problem?
Thank in advance.

---

After few experts help here, I can solve the problem:

- re-install express

I used npm install -g express-generator@3 command yesterday, so it make my global setting to express version 3.  I uninstall and install express again first.

```
npm uninstall -g express-generator@3
npm uninstall -g express
npm install -g express
npm install -g express-generator
```

- Remove local node_modules

After step 1, same problem is still exist, I found that i installed express 3.x in local working folder before, so I create a new working folder, restart the example code again, problem is gone

Comment: replace var express = require('express'); with var express = require('express')();

Comment: What version of Express do you use?

Comment: thx for your help, after modifying to require('express')(); error message move to the following line, TypeError: express.Router is not a function

Comment: express --version shows 3.0.0

Comment: `express.Router()` is an Express 4.x thing.

Comment: Upgrade Express to 4.x version

Comment: i run npm install -g express-generator again, now, express --version shows 4.13.1, but problem is still the same  TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined

Comment: Try to remove  now `()` adviced by @Ben

Comment: removing or adding () cannot solved the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial you are following is written based on 4.x version of Express framework. There were made [significant changes regarding routing process](http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html#routing) in Express 4.x, comparing with 3.x version. In particular, [`express.Router()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router) object was added. So, or you have to adept your code ([this](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x) might help you), in order to make it work, or to upgrade Express versions.

Comment: this is one good hit, but cannot solve my problem completely.

Comment: I fix the last issue, it's coming from local node_modules.  Yesterday, when i do the setup i installed express 3.x into local working folder.  after I re-create the example working folder, express 4 works well now.
Thank everybody here.

Comment: I had a similar issue; I was using ^3.0.0 version in package.json, since trying to use 5.3.0 would cause an error when trying to run npm install.  It said something like version does not match (exist!! crazy).  In the end, I changed to 4.16.0 in package.json and now the server is behaving.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **typescript & es6** imports, and run into the same problem.

use:

```
import * as passport from "passport";
```

instead of

```
import passport from "passport";
```

refer to: [Typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import)

Answer (score -1):

I ran into similar problem. I placed the code after `app.use(express.static...)` and it worked.